# How to erase vanished files on linux system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage

I have one server at packet.net and I have attached external volume which is mounted to folder /BACKUP where I process backup. Yesterday I have received an email that there is a problem with main partition - it is almost full? Somehow, attached volume de-attaches and mount /BACKUP was (I guess) unmounted and several backups was done in this folder which "switches" to local drive. When I attach external volume again, /BACKUP folder was automatically mounted to it. I delete all files on it, but main partition still shows it is full 90%.

When I check with df, I see this result:

```
[root@packet /]# df
Filesystem                    1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3                      74824932 64793724   6207284  92% /
devtmpfs                        4069428        0   4069428   0% /dev
tmpfs                           4081476        4   4081472   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           4081476   123644   3957832   4% /run
tmpfs                           4081476        0   4081476   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                            816296        0    816296   0% /run/user/10003
tmpfs                            816296        0    816296   0% /run/user/0
/dev/mapper/volume-1cb9df94p1  61795116    53704  58579352   1% /BACKUP
```

the I wanted to find where those 3 backups gone, and searched for large folders.

```
[root@packet /]# du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 5
26593808        /
17031172        /var
13973568        /var/www
13968748        /var/www/vhosts
8188140 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com
```

So it looks like / folder is large 26 Gb (which should be correct), but in df it shows 64 Gb occupation, like those three backups (~12Gb each) vanishes... How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They seem to still be in the /BACKUP folder. When you mount the drive, what was in the folder is now hidden by the mount point. to remove the hidden files you will need to `unmount /BACKUP` and `rm /BACKUP/*` the files after unmounting.

Comment: when I attached volume back, there were files that were originally on the drive. Not yet tried to unmount and mount again

Comment: yep, when I umount /BACKUP I found files back. Deleted all of them and now is OK. I just cant mount back because "mount: /dev/sdc is already mounted or /BACKUP busy" but will find out how to manage that (I guess). It is not mounted, checked, but it is Busy...

Comment: @ВојинПетровић leave the directory and it will stop being busy

Comment: I'm not in a directory :) I have tried to mount it to newly created folder /BKP, but it is still busy

Comment: I have tried now to mount it to /BKP, but same error. When I list all mounts there is no sdc in mounts

Comment: try a lazy unmount on the directory `unmount -l /BACKUP` that will let it take its time. If you want to push, you can disconnect the backup drive and reconnect, or reboot

Comment: it is not mounted...
`[root@packet /]# umount -l /BACKUP
umount: /BACKUP: not mounted
`

Comment: `[root@packet /]# umount /dev/sdc`
`umount: /dev/sdc: not mounted`
`[root@packet /]# mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc /BKP`
`mount: /dev/sdc is already mounted or /BKP busy`

Comment: hmm... seems sdc is doing something. Do you get anything when doing a `grep sdc /etc/mtab`?

Comment: GAHHH, please stop trying to mount (or worse mkfs) /dev/sdc. Look at the `df` output — pretty clear LVM (or some other device-mapper thing) is in use, and you need to mount `/dev/mapper/volume-1cb9df94p1`

Comment: After reboot, it remounted automatically .. all works fine. Thanks.